# Apache error in error.log while running Yii application

Tags: apache, yii

When testing my yii application in ubuntu machine, /var/log/apache2/error.log is displaying the following error, every time I access a page.

client denied by server configuration: /var/www/item, referer: https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/storemgr/issue/manage

No error logging when tested in Windows.

**But I am NOT facing any problem in accessing pages in browser.**

Url used by me: https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/storemgr/item/manage

My Apache configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/storemgr/>
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Url Manager in main.php

```
    'urlManager'=>array
    (
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array
        (
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

.htaccess content of webroot (ie. storemgr)

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</ifModule>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

config.php

```
'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'caseSensitive' => false,
            'rules' => require(SITE_PATH_CONFIG . '_routes.php'
                )
        ),
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName siteName
    DocumentRoot /folder/name

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /folder/name/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Check your configs again. Also want to say that there is issues with routes in "Windows" based adaptation - simple example is "\" not equal "/" so in *nix-list and Windows OS it can be trouble.

Also re-check your routes. It route it matched it will be used, so first add (to routes array) routes short routes, simple exmaple how it should be

```
'some/<id>/<action>' => 'some/doAction',
'some/<id>/someAction' => 'some/doActionSome'
```

Second one never be used. So you should add it first.

PS: Best way to figure where trouble is - is to find where it crashes, on what controller/method etc. When you find - you can look there what route is used and understand your trouble (or ask question). Without it no-one can help you with your question.

Comment: AFAICS, its not Yii fault but apache one

Comment: Really? Hm, please show me your route for  https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/storemgr/issue/manage I see three vars storemgr (controller?), issue (action?), manage (var?) but no route for it. You have sub folders? Routes you showed are incorrect.

Comment: I think trouble is in this 'webroot', try to get Yii::app()->controller->id and Yii::app()->controller->action->id to see does controller name and action is right. Also you didn't show where and how you declare your root folder in Yii.

Answer (score 0):

Its no Yii issue at all. I guess you upgraded recently to 13.10 Saucy.
Its a change in Apache Server. You need to add new directive: granted
Here is an example

```
<Directory /var/www/storemgr/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   # New directive for new Apache 
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

See changes when upgrading to  2.4 [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)